# How do you take only some gold out of a sack in Nethack with numpad movement on?

Tags: nethack

I used credit cloning very successfully and now I have a lot of gold in my sack.

I play with numpad for movement and I haven't figured out how to remove only some of the gold. The nethack wiki instructions for stack splitting don't seem to work with numpad movement: [https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Stackable#:~:text=Splitting%20stacks,to%20drop%204%20of%20them](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Stackable#:%7E:text=Splitting%20stacks,to%20drop%204%20of%20them).

How do I go about taking only some of a stack out of a container with numpad movement on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is different for NetHack.exe (the console version with text display) and NetHackW.exe (the default GUI application). This answer is for vanilla 3.6.6; variants might change things. I'm also only on Windows. I'm using `t` as the sack in this instance.

For NetHackW.exe:

`a` `t` `o` `b` `Enter` `Down` `Down` `500` (checkbox should change to a "#").

Pressing Down on the arrow keys is needed to select the Gold from the list, after the "Coins" header. Using the mouse to click on it also works. It looks like a-zA-Z automatically selects items, but $ doesn't, which is why this isn't needed for other items.

I don't believe numpad movement changes anything. Once the gold is selected from the list, you can type out the count with either the numpad or the number keys.

For NetHack.exe:

`a` `t` `o` `b` `500$`. The display should change to a "#", not a "-" or "+"